# Stripe "insufficient funds" credit card failing authentication?

Tags: stripe-payments

I've just finished setting up Stripe payment gateway and currently set environment to testing mode. I've also done some testing on valid credit cards and everything went well, however when I attempt to test VALID credit cards but with different payment issues (like insufficient funds) the authentication of the card fails with of course, `insufficient_funds` error.

How can I find other test cards that will successfully authenticate but will fail the charge process? I'm using predefined payment methods so this is vital for the application user flow.

Here are the cards I've tested from the [stripe docs](https://stripe.com/docs/testing):

- `4000000000009995`: fails to authenticate.
- `4000008260003178`: successfully authenticates and charges although when quoting the docs it says "This card requires authentication for one-time payments. All payments will be declined with an insufficient_funds failure code even after being successfully authenticated or previously set up."

Here are the server logs for the card I'm expecting to fail:

```
2020-02-11T15:03:20.383813+00:00 app[web.1]: preauthorizeOrder. transaction result:  {
2020-02-11T15:03:20.383822+00:00 app[web.1]:   isSuccessful: true,
2020-02-11T15:03:20.383822+00:00 app[web.1]:   transaction: {
2020-02-11T15:03:20.383823+00:00 app[web.1]:     id: 'pi_1GB0GiDg9Exxxxxxxxxxxx',
2020-02-11T15:03:20.383823+00:00 app[web.1]:     object: 'payment_intent',
2020-02-11T15:03:20.383823+00:00 app[web.1]:     amount: 451,
2020-02-11T15:03:20.383824+00:00 app[web.1]:     amount_capturable: 0,
2020-02-11T15:03:20.383824+00:00 app[web.1]:     amount_received: 0,
2020-02-11T15:03:20.383825+00:00 app[web.1]:     application: null,
2020-02-11T15:03:20.383825+00:00 app[web.1]:     application_fee_amount: null,
2020-02-11T15:03:20.383826+00:00 app[web.1]:     canceled_at: null,
2020-02-11T15:03:20.383826+00:00 app[web.1]:     cancellation_reason: null,
2020-02-11T15:03:20.383826+00:00 app[web.1]:     capture_method: 'automatic',
2020-02-11T15:03:20.383827+00:00 app[web.1]:     charges: {
2020-02-11T15:03:20.383828+00:00 app[web.1]:       object: 'list',
2020-02-11T15:03:20.383828+00:00 app[web.1]:       data: [],
2020-02-11T15:03:20.383828+00:00 app[web.1]:       has_more: false,
2020-02-11T15:03:20.383829+00:00 app[web.1]:       total_count: 0,
2020-02-11T15:03:20.383829+00:00 app[web.1]:       url: '/v1/charges?payment_intent=pi_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
2020-02-11T15:03:20.383830+00:00 app[web.1]:     },
2020-02-11T15:03:20.383831+00:00 app[web.1]:     client_secret: 'pi_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_secret_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
2020-02-11T15:03:20.383831+00:00 app[web.1]:     confirmation_method: 'manual',
2020-02-11T15:03:20.383832+00:00 app[web.1]:     created: 1581433400,
2020-02-11T15:03:20.383834+00:00 app[web.1]:     currency: 'cad',
2020-02-11T15:03:20.383834+00:00 app[web.1]:     customer: 'cus_Gi4lxxxxxxxxxxxx',
2020-02-11T15:03:20.383835+00:00 app[web.1]:     description: 'burger bob - pizza',
2020-02-11T15:03:20.383835+00:00 app[web.1]:     invoice: null,
2020-02-11T15:03:20.383835+00:00 app[web.1]:     last_payment_error: null,
2020-02-11T15:03:20.383836+00:00 app[web.1]:     livemode: false,
2020-02-11T15:03:20.383836+00:00 app[web.1]:     metadata: {},
2020-02-11T15:03:20.383836+00:00 app[web.1]:     next_action: null,
2020-02-11T15:03:20.383837+00:00 app[web.1]:     on_behalf_of: null,
2020-02-11T15:03:20.383837+00:00 app[web.1]:     payment_method: 'pm_1GBxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
2020-02-11T15:03:20.383838+00:00 app[web.1]:     payment_method_options: { card: [Object] },
2020-02-11T15:03:20.383838+00:00 app[web.1]:     payment_method_types: [ 'card' ],
2020-02-11T15:03:20.383839+00:00 app[web.1]:     receipt_email: null,
2020-02-11T15:03:20.383839+00:00 app[web.1]:     review: null,
2020-02-11T15:03:20.383839+00:00 app[web.1]:     setup_future_usage: null,
2020-02-11T15:03:20.383839+00:00 app[web.1]:     shipping: null,
2020-02-11T15:03:20.383840+00:00 app[web.1]:     source: null,
2020-02-11T15:03:20.383840+00:00 app[web.1]:     statement_descriptor: null,
2020-02-11T15:03:20.383841+00:00 app[web.1]:     statement_descriptor_suffix: null,
2020-02-11T15:03:20.383841+00:00 app[web.1]:     status: 'requires_confirmation',
2020-02-11T15:03:20.383841+00:00 app[web.1]:     transfer_data: null,
2020-02-11T15:03:20.383842+00:00 app[web.1]:     transfer_group: null
2020-02-11T15:03:20.383842+00:00 app[web.1]:   }
```

Comment: Can you clarify whether you are working on testing Authentication vs Authorization? Additionally, if you can post a snippet of the request or client call you are trying to make, it will allow us to assist you better.

Depending on what you're trying to accomplish, you may just need to confirm the payment intent: https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/confirm

However, the test card `4000008260003178 ` is a 3D Secure v2 test card, and requires you handle the authentication challenge. Find a demo here: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment

Comment: Thanks Nolan, I've reached out to Stripe support with full details and they said it's not possible to do it. This thread may be closed.